# BetterCharacterControl not applying RigidBody at the right Position

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine, jbullet

So Im new to JME3 and I have a few problems understanding the BetterCharacterControl.

When I try to apply a BetterCharacterControl to a box it always "expands" from the upper part of the box instead of the center. (A picture explains that better:)

[image: The Problem]

I cant find any functions to change the location it gets applied at, I already tried to create a subclass in which I changed the RigidBody to the BoxCollisionShape directly but that seems to somehow screw up the isOnGround Method. Also if I want to use slopes later it would be nice to have the capsule shape.

```
Box box2 = new Box(10, 15, 10);
player = new Geometry("Player", box2);
player.setLocalTranslation(new Vector3f(0, 20, 0));
Material mat = new Material(assetManager, 
            "Common/MatDefs/Light/Lighting.j3md");
mat.setBoolean("UseMaterialColors", true);
mat.setColor("Ambient", ColorRGBA.Blue);
mat.setColor("Diffuse", ColorRGBA.Blue);
player.setMaterial(mat);

playerC = new BetterCharacterControl(12, 30, 0);
playerC.setJumpForce(new Vector3f(0, 700, 0));
player.addControl(playerC);

rootNode.attachChild(player);

bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(playerC);
```

On a different note, it seems like I i have to apply a huge vector for the jump force for it to do anything (I didnt change any gravity values)

Im glad for any help

Comment: How do you feel about doing it the other way round; making the graphics fit the physics. I'd just use a node to move box2 around relative to the player (or just set a local translation for the box)

Answer (score 0):

i had this same problem. The way I resolved it is not usual. I coded a class and did inherit from BetterCharacterControl overwriting getShape() method as follows:

```
protected CollisionShape getShape() {
    //TODO: cleanup size mess..
    CapsuleCollisionShape capsuleCollisionShape = new CapsuleCollisionShape(getFinalRadius(), (getFinalHeight() - (2 * getFinalRadius())));
    CompoundCollisionShape compoundCollisionShape = new CompoundCollisionShape();
    //Vector3f addLocation = new Vector3f(0, (getFinalHeight() / 2.0f), 0); REMOVED LINE
    Vector3f addLocation = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0); //NEW LINE
    compoundCollisionShape.addChildShape(capsuleCollisionShape, addLocation);
    return compoundCollisionShape;
}
```

This works because the original code is a composite created in such a way so that the child node is offset by the value: (getFinalHeight () / 2.0f). The new line adds not realize this shift, leaving the object in the center position of the box set. However, this way of solving the problem, it can create problems when actually a composite mesh is used in the final object.